# How can I set Timezone in lumen 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

I did not find any relevant information (only tricks) about how to set the default timezone in Lumen 5.2. Is there any clean way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty easily done and shown in their [documentation page](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#accessing-configuration-values):

> To set configuration values at runtime, pass an array to the config
>   helper:

```
config(['app.timezone' => 'America/Chicago']);
```

Alternatively, in `app/config.php`:

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

Comment: It should be in `config/app.php`. And we must call: `$app->configure('app')`, to make it works.

Comment: @edgji 's answer is right. The question is to change the default timezone.

Comment: The above does so. His answer is an alternative.

Answer (score 16):

In Lumen 5.2 the Application class actually reads from a APP_TIMEZONE environment variable.

You can easily set timezone via a .env file using or setting the environment variable on your server:

```
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
```

Answer (score 7):

None of the responses I've read in a lot of forums solves the problem, because in the file /vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/database.php there is this line:

```html
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
            'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8_unicode_ci'),
            'prefix'    => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
            **'timezone'  => env('DB_TIMEZONE', '+00:00'),**
            'strict'    => env('DB_STRICT_MODE', false),
        ],
```

You need to rewrite this config file. Create a database.php file in config folder. Then copy all the content without the timezone line. This works for me.

Comment: I think we just need to set the `DB_TIMEZONE` in `.env` file.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me regarding DST

Answer (score 5):

You can add your timezone in your `.env` file

```
APP_TIMEZONE=YOUR_TIME_ZONE
```

Docs:

[List of Timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

[Lumen Documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

Comment: This is far simpler then the other answers

Answer (score 2):

Just to resume and be super clear (at this year 2018):

> All of the configuration options for the Lumen framework are stored in
>   the .env file.

In Lumen **does not exist** a `config/app.php` file.

---

But also, if we look at `vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php`

```
/**
 * Create a new Lumen application instance.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $basePath
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($basePath = null)
{
    ...
        date_default_timezone_set(env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'));
    ...
```

ref:  https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.6/src/Application.php#L83

We see that Lumen will not take any `config` value, just an `env` value to set the time zone.

So the technique of copy/paste `/laravel/lumen-framework/config directory` to use `full "Laravel style" configuration files` in Lumen is not applicable in this case, and never was.

Besides: that technique is an old reference to the first version of Lumen.
ref: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1#configuration-files. (old docs)

In the current version 5.6 of Lumen that tip has been removed from the documentation and probably was a tip to help migrating from Laravel in the initial times of Lumen but is not longer a good practice. **So use .env files always**.
ref: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.6#configuration (new docs)

Answer (score 1):

In `config/app.php`
 you can change it

> 'timezone' => 'UTC',